# Windows compile unix exe c++

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I want to ask if i can compile c++ unix exe on windows by not including MingW in the makefile... Im thinking of switching to windows but Im scared that Im not able to compile for linux or mac.

Comment: Unless you have a Mac, you can't compile for Mac.

Comment: I do im using it but ima trash it

Comment: "Unix' is a family of Operating Systems, including Mac OSX but not actually Linux (which is merely Unix-like). You can't compile for the whole family. As for Windows, that can run pretty much any Linux program these days including `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)